# Most Stable Version of Drools

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata, drools

We are planning to use Drools in our organisation with Scala/Spark. We have selected Drools Version 5.3.0 and 7.15.0 for our use but we have some stability doubts between them because Version 7.15.0 has recently launched & we are not sure whether it is stable or not.

We have practiced with Version 5.3.0 but we want to know the life cycle of it. What if after some time, Version 5.3.0 will not available for use or some update is brought for this?

So please help us to chose between them which version should we chose for longer use.

Answer (score 1):

Drools 5.3 is outdated version and its not under development. Its better you go with latest release.Drools 7.15 is also stable, but if you are planning to use it for business critical application then I will recommend you to go with enterprise release of Drools 7.x , i.e Red Hat Decision Manager. With enterprise release will get patches for known issue on regular basis and one-off patch for critical issues.